# Liberty & Ubuntu - Any concern to work togheter?

Tags: ubuntu, websphere-liberty

Any knowed concern to use Liberty & Ubuntu togheter? What is the version of Ubuntu suggested? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is supported to install latest Liberty (v9 aka 16.0.0.2) on Ubuntu 12, 14 and 16. For more details check [WebSphere Liberty supported Linux versions](http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/osForProduct?deliverableId=1380722700161&osPlatforms=Linux&duComponentIds=S002|S001|S004|S003)